# How to save value of Text Field in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am novice at Core Data. Need to save value of Text Field. I have done:

Model.xcdatamodeld: "Entity" -> "attribute" (Integer 32);

And wrote the code but I am not sure:

```
//ViewController.h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textOutlet;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

//ViewController.m
    -(id)init{

        NSString *const kDtabaseFileName=@"file.sqlite";
        NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *databasePath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDtabaseFileName];

        NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel=[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator=[[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
        [persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[NSURL URLWithString:databasePath] options:nil error:nil];
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext=[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]init];
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator=persistentStoreCoordinator;
        self.managedObjectContext=managedObjectContext;

        return self;
    }
```

What to do next?

Comment: Have you managed to get a callback when the text changes? Concentrate on that first.

Comment: The init code is also wrong. Use the Apple code samples to guide you. Also, I think you only need the `managedObjectContext`.

Comment: I used Apple code - Master Detail, but a lot of class that I do not need. I am lost)

Comment: @Wain I am going now to use method "Editing Changed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyObject *myObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyObject" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

myObject.field = anything;
```

Maybe these lines of code can help